# How to create 2 tables using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE only once?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a requirement where I need to create 2 tables inside a `PLSQL` block. Currently we're using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. Now the issue is I need to create 2 tables but I can use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` only once.

Are there ways to create tables within `PLSQL` either by
1) without using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`
or 2) create 2 tables inside a single usage of `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`

I tried like below. and some trail and error combinations. but didnt help.
Expecting like the below.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
'BEGIN
  CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE1 AS
  SELECT T1.*,
    ''Y'' PROCESS_FLAG
  FROM TABLE1 T1
  WHERE T1.PRIMAR_ID IN ( 300000005137174 ,300000005142005);
  CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE2 AS
  SELECT T2.*,
    ''Y'' PROCESS_FLAG
  FROM TABLE2 T2
  WHERE T2.CODE       IS NULL
  AND T2.SECONDARY_ID IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT(T_TEMP.PRIMAR_ID)
    FROM NEW_TABLE1 T_TEMP
    WHERE T_TEMP.PROCESS_FLAG = ''Y''
    );
END' ;
```

Comment: I am trying but getting errors.

Comment: I tried by having both create stmts in a single string and execute with one EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. But erroring. Not sure if syntax problem or the try itself is wrong.

Comment: what did you try, could you add your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I admit it's not very nice but you can run multiple `execute immediate` inside a `plsql` block in an `execute immediate`:

```
begin
    execute immediate '
        begin
            execute immediate ''create table a(c number)'';
            execute immediate ''create table b(c number)'';
        end;
    ';
end;
```

#### EDIT:

As per your comment, you can run the following.

```
begin
    execute immediate '
        BEGIN 
            execute immediate ''
                CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE1 AS 
                SELECT T1.*, ''''Y'''' PROCESS_FLAG
                FROM TABLE1 T1 
                WHERE T1.PRIMAR_ID IN ( 300000005137174 ,300000005142005)
            '';

            execute immediate ''
                CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE2 AS 
                SELECT T2.*, ''''Y'''' PROCESS_FLAG
                FROM TABLE2 T2
                WHERE T2.CODE IS NULL 
                AND T2.SECONDARY_ID IN (
                    SELECT distinct(T_TEMP.PRIMAR_ID)
                    FROM NEW_TABLE1 T_TEMP
                    WHERE T_TEMP.PROCESS_FLAG = ''''Y''''
                )
            ''; 
        END;
    ';
end;
```

Also, you may need to rethink your problem. Do you really need to *create* table? Can you not create the tables beforehand and just do simple insertion instead. You can circumvent dynamic SQL.

Comment: Hi.. I am looking for something like this..

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE1 AS 
         SELECT T1.*, ''Y'' PROCESS_FLAG FROM TABLE1 T1 
         WHERE T1.PRIMAR_ID IN ( 300000005137174
                 ,300000005142005);
                          CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE2 AS 
         SELECT T2.*, ''Y'' PROCESS_FLAG FROM TABLE2 T2 
         WHERE T2.CODE IS NULL AND T2.SECONDARY_ID IN (SELECT distinct(T_TEMP.PRIMAR_ID)
                  FROM NEW_TABLE1 T_TEMP
                  WHERE T_TEMP.PROCESS_FLAG = ''Y''
                 ); END' ;

Comment: please refer below.. my comment as a separate answer. (To have a good formated look of the SQL)

Comment: @GokulNath - You may need rethink your problem.. Perhaps you dont need to create the table - have them created once.. And have your code do just the insertion